# Azure Data Factory declare a "Copy Data" reusable over pipelines

Tags: azure-data-factory, copy-database-wizard

I've made a copy data object that logs process info about the pipeline into a SQL Table. This copy data activity is generic in use and can be applied to all of my pipelines... but how can i declare this specific copy data as a reusable object for all my pipelines?

Comment: Activities (other than Data Flows) aren't reusable across multiple pipelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a separate pipeline in Data Factory that contains only the generic copy activity. This pipeline can then be executed (reused) from all your pipelines.

[Execute Pipeline activity in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-execute-pipeline-activity)